# MS Access - matching a small data set with a very large data set

Tags: performance, ms-access, indexing

I have a huge excel file with more than a million rows and a bunch of columns (300) which I've imported to an access database. I'm trying to run an inner join query on it which matches on a numeric field in a relatively small dataset. I would like to capture all the columns of data from the huge dataset if possible. I was able to get the query to run in about 1/2 hour when I selected just one column from the huge dataset. However, when I select all the columns from the larger dataset, and have the query writes to a table, it just never stops.

One consideration is that the smaller dataset's join field is a number, while the larger one's is in text. To get around this, I created a query on the larger dataset which converts the text field to a number using the "val" function. The text field in question is indexed, but I'm thinking I should convert on the table itself to a numeric field to match the smaller dataset's type. Maybe that would make the lookup more efficient.

Other than that, I could use and would greatly appreciate some suggestions of a good strategy to get this query to run in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: If you do that, you lose all advatages of indexes, and you need them for large queries. Can you not convert the small table data type to match the large table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access is a relational database. It is designed to work efficiently if your structure respects the relational model. Volume is not the issue.

Step 1: normalize your data. If you don't have a clue about what that means, there is a wizard in Access that can help you for this (Database Tools, Analyze table) , or search for **Database normalization**
Step 2: index the join fields
Step 3: enjoy fast results

Your idea of having both sides of the join in the same type IS a must. If you don't do that, indexes and optimisation won't be able to operate.